# Is it possible to make an ignore-this decorator for coverage?

Tags: python, code-coverage

I built a simple decorator that I hope will cause coverage to ignore anything to which it is applied. Empirically, it has no effects. The only way I know to turn off coverage for a block of code is `# pragma: no cover` - is there any way to move that into the business logic?

```
def deco(fn):
    return fn  # pragma: no cover

@deco
def uncover_me(x):
    if x > 1:
        return 3
    return 5


uncover_me(3)
uncover_me(0)
```

Comment: What is the end goal? Why do you wish to use ```@deco``` instead of ```# pragma: no cover```?

Comment: Maybe to control it - "if function name is `foo`, then `# pragma: no cover`, but only if user configured `bar = 99`"

Comment: I want to attach it to decorators we already have.

Answer (score 1):

In your .coveragerc file, you can specify regexes that will exclude lines (described in [Advanced exclusion](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.2/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion)).

If the regex matches a line introducing a clause of code, then the whole clause is excluded.  Excluding a decorator will exclude the entire function.

This should work for you:

```
# in .coveragerc
[report]
exclude_lines =
    @deco
    pragma: no cover
```

From the docs:

> Note that when using the exclude_lines option in a configuration file, you are taking control of the entire list of regexes, so you need to re-specify the default “pragma: no cover” match if you still want it to apply.

Comment: On 3.7 it does not seem to do this in practice.

Comment: Can you open a coverage.py issue about it so we can work through the details? https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/

Comment: Will do in a bit